# how to restart/clear memcache without restarting the whole web server?

Tags: memcached, php

`/opt/eduserver/eduserver` gives me options:

> Usage: /opt/eduserver/eduserver 
>   {start|stop|startphp|startwww|startooo|stopphp|stopwww|stopooo|restartphp|restartwww|restartooo|status|restart|reload|force-reload}

where memcache is php module there is `memcache.ini` in `/opt/eduserver/etc/php/conf.d`.

I want to clear the memcache from command line. Can I do it somehow without 'touching' any other part of the web server?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

yes. you can clear the memcache. try:

```
telnet localhost 11211
flush_all
quit
```

if the memcache does not run on localhost 11211, you will have to adjust it.

Comment: Can I do this non interactively?

Comment: I'm trying to verify this actually was effective. So far stats still shows total_items 3926. I was expecting total_items to drop to 0. Is that not how to verify the cache was flushed?

Comment: @DannyArmstrong, flush only marks items as expired.  Memcache doesn't remove expired items from the cache straight away for performance reasons. You can get expired items, so they have vanished from an API perspective

Comment: @TerryE - Do you mean to say "You can't get expired items" rather than "You can get expired items"?

Comment: Yes I do.  Sorry

Answer (score 44):

This will also work using netcat

```
echo "flush_all" | nc -q 2 localhost 11211
```

Then just wait for the "OK".

Comment: w/o hardcoded 2 seconds: `printf "flush_all\nquit\n" | nc -q -1 127.1 11211`

Comment: OSX needs -w for timeout: `echo "flush_all" | nc -w 2 localhost 11211`

Comment: w/o quit & wait: `printf "flush_all" | nc localhost 11211`

Answer (score 26):

`memcflush` in the memcache tools is what you want:

```
memcflush --servers=localhost:11211
```

Change `localhost` to whatever your server is.

The memcache tools may not be installed on the server, if you're running a Debian-based OS you can install it like this:

```
sudo apt-get install libmemcached-tools
```

Comment: In Red Hat distributions, the utility is included in `libmemcached`.

Comment: We use `memcflush --servers=127.0.0.1:11211` to avoid localhost: https://github.com/littlebizzy/slickstack/blob/master/bash/ss-purge-memcached.txt

Answer (score 12):

In Bash you may use this fancy syntax:

```
echo flush_all > /dev/tcp/localhost/11211
```

Otherwise use `memflush` command:

```
memflush --servers=localhost
```

Comment: As telnet and nc was not available on our servers, the first solution works fine, thanks.

Comment: `echo flush_all > /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/11211` also should work for those who don't want to use the localhost, see: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-flush-contents-of-memcached-instance/

Answer (score 4):

`(sleep 2; echo flush_all; sleep 2; echo quit; ) | telnet 127.0.0.1 11211`

if you want to run it non-interactively

thanks to @heiko

Comment: This worked for me, as I had a host where I didn't want to install `nc.  Note that I worked fine for me without either the initial `sleep` or the final `quit`.  I did `( echo 'flush_all' ; sleep 2 ) | telnet myhost.fqdn.com 11211`

Answer (score 4):

Rather than waiting for timeouts you can make the command instantaneous by following [`flush_all`](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/wiki/Commands#flush_all)  with the `quit` command:

`printf "flush_all\r\nquit\r\n" | nc localhost 11211`

Alternatively if you don't have `nc`:

`printf "flush_all\r\nquit\r\n" > /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/11211`

Though this method won't produce an output, although you can verify it works by checking [`stats`](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/wiki/Commands#stats) to see that `cmd_flush` increased.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function to flush memcached via PHP, in case that you need to refresh it without logging into ssh...

You can just http://yourserver.com/memflush.php

Call this file memflush.php

```
<?php

 $socket = fsockopen("localhost", "11211", $errno, $errstr); 

    if($socket) { 
        echo "Connected. <br /><br />"; 
    }
    else { 
        echo "Connection failed!<br /><br />"; 
    }

    fputs($socket, "flush_all\r\n"); 
    $buffer = ""; 

    fclose($socket); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

in case you use a socket for connecting to memcached the syntax is

`echo "flush_all" | nc -U ~/memcached.sock`